# In ASP.NET MVC, how do I allow for anonymous and Windows authentication

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, authentication, iis

I have a `ASP.NET MVC` webapp running on IIS. In `IIS` I have only `Windows authentication` enabled. I have now a requirement that certain area must be allowed to access by public.
What I have done, is that I created a new [area](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee671793%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) that contains the Controller for public. Basically if my controllers live in *Project.Controllers* folder then that one is *Project.Areas.PublicArea.Controllers*.

I created a new section to `web.config`

```
  <location path="~/Areas/PublicArea/Controllers">
    <system.web>
      <authentication mode="None"></authentication>
      <authorization>
        <allow users="?"/>
      </authorization>
    </system.web>
  </location>
```

And annotated the new controller with `[AllowAnonymous]`. I have not done any changes to `IIS`. (Actaully I tried to enable anon authorization as well, but that seems to be default and come before Windows authorization, which does not suit me).

Currently when I try to access the PublicArea without authorization, I still get `HTTP.401`.

What is the easiest way accomplish a situation where all the app is using `Windows Auth` and part of it is allowed for public?

Comment: Just an idea: Create a class that derives from Controller and add your [Authorize] Attribute to the class level. Then each other controller will derive from this class. If any action is an exception to the generic rule, then add [AllowAnonymous] to that action.